# JS: UI countown for setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, user-interface, countdown

I have a page that runs `reloadData()` function every 5 seconds:

```
setTimeout('reloadData()', 5000);
```

I have an element that I'd like to update with a countdown from 5 to 0 for every second of the reloadData();

```
document.getElementById('countdown').value
```

What is the proper way to do achieve this effect?

Example:

- `reloadData() {}` starts
- Element "`countdown`" will show: 5... 4... 3...
  2... 1... (at second intervals)
- `reloadData(){}` starts again

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely sure how to interpreter your question, but I guess you have a function `reloadData` which should run every 5 second.

You will now have a counter showed which will found from 5..1 for each second.

When then counter reaches 0 you want to repeat, eg calling `reloadData()` and count again?

```
var counter = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  if (counter == 0) {
    reloadData();
  }
  // do stuff with i which will be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
  // ...
  document.getElementById('countdown').value = 5 - counter;
  // ...
  counter++;
  counter %= 5;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: bad practice for true second wise ticks

Comment: `true second wise ticks`?

Comment: yep. you are implying your code takes 0 ms to run through aswell as this function fires -exactly- one second after calling this settimeout. besides that, you will not run this function more than once since its not repeating (its not an interval.. wich is bad in this case too)

Comment: @GottZ I ment to use `setInterval`, thanks for the heads up

Comment: now that you updated it to `setInterval` you might also want to trigger `clearInterval` as soon as the counter reaches 0. and no. its still a bad timer.

Comment: @GottZ Depends on OP wants the code to run forever which is how i interpreted the question. Correct me if I'm wrong. :-)

Comment: na. OP is saying he want it to count from 5 to 0.

Comment: just a small info on why i say setTimeout / setInterval is bad: it will run out of sync. to get around this you need to work with timestamps and calculate offsets wich you use as timeout aswell as register a new timeout as soon as your callback finished. try to create a clock that prints the current time every second into your console. you will notice what i mean.

Comment: @GottZ I don't think OP needs that amount of precision. `setInterval` will try to run every second even if the code takes 500 ms to execute. While `a=()=> setTimeout(() => { /*cpu intensive stuff ... 500ms later*/ a();}`, 1000)` will not

Comment: well if you like this kind of precision: http://i.imgur.com/KyeFKs8.png continue using `setInterval`. its actually not a bad choice for OP's question. must be the perfectionist in me.

Answer (score 0):

More like 6 seconds because I hang out on reload for a bit, but you can use requestAnimationFrame to call your function (about 60 times a second) and check the date to see if you're over a second. Then update your counter.

As in this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/subterrane/k2aacj4s/

Output div:

```
<div class="container" id="counter"></div>
```

Some script:

```
var counter = document.querySelector("#counter");
var count = 5;
var start = Date.now();

function work() {
  if (count == 0) {
    counter.innerText = "reload!";
  } else {
    counter.innerText = count;
  }

  var now = Date.now();
  if (now >= start + 1000) {
    start = now;
    count--;
    if(count < 0) count = 5;
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(work);
};

work();
```